# How can I know the time to completion of a ParticleEffect

Tags: java, libgdx, effects, particles

Is there a way to get the time until completion of a `ParticleEffect` in `libgdx`?
For example, say I want something to happen one second before the `ParticleEffect` completes:

```
private void foo(){
    ParticleEffect bombEffect = new ParticleEffect();
    bombEffect.load(Gdx.files.internal("particles/bomb.p"), atlas);
    .
    .
    .
    if(timeToCompletion(bombEffect) < 1){ 
        // do something
    }
    .
    .
    . 
}

private float timeToCompletion(ParticleEffect pEffect){
    // How can this be implemented??
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know the duration of particle effect. Than you can count time in some variable. And than check if duration - thistime < 1. Maybe this is not the best solution, but it will work.

One more idea is to extend your own class from ParticleEffect and implement this functionality there, and you will be able to call something like yourEffect.getPassedTime ();

Hope this will be useful for you. Good luck.

Comment: 1.  How do I know the duration of the particle effect?
2. You are right. Once I understand how to do this, extending `ParticleEffect` is the better way to go.

Comment: Particle effect has method setDuration.

Comment: That method sets the duration. There is no `getDuration` method.

Comment: But if you can setDuration and you know when you fire your particles, then you can calculate time passed

Comment: I don't use `setDuration`. I'm using a particle editor to build the properties of the particle. Since the duration is random (between two `Min` and `Max` values) I don't know the exact duration of the particle when it is created.

Comment: Oh ok, I understood. I'll think a while.